# Keep Parent li as class hovered while navigation a submenu

Tags: html, css

I have built a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQesS/) for this. What I am looking to do is, Once you navigate to the submenu, It keeps the padding around the parent li item. At the moment, If you hover over the li, You can see the padding.

My CSS is as follows :

```
#access {
    margin-top: 45px;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav {
    margin:0 0 10px 15px;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav li {
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav li a {
    color: #336c82;
    padding: 10px;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav ul {
    display: none;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav li a:hover {
    background: #336c82;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: -25px;
    background: #336c82;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav ul.sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav ul.sub-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
}

#access ul#menu-top_nav ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and my HTML is :

```
<div role="navigation" id="access">
<ul id="menu-top_nav" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17" id="menu-item-17">
        <a href="#">Our Business</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73" id="menu-item-73"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72" id="menu-item-72"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But going further into the sub menu the hover effect goes off.

How can I make it so that the parent li is always of effect hover?

Thanks in advance. Hope I've explained properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `#access ul#menu-top_nav li a:hover` to `#access ul#menu-top_nav li:hover a`

```
    #access ul#menu-top_nav li:hover a{
    background: #336c82;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tQesS/3/)

**[HERE](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/11/pure-css-dropdown-menu.html)** is the detailed example of CSS drop-down menu.

Comment: Thats perfect, So adding a new particular class for the parent does the trick. Thank you one for future knowledge.

Comment: @StuBlackett I didn't add any new class. Just changed your existing class

Comment: I see from your modified answer, Changing the a:hover to li:hover. Thanks @Sowmya

Comment: have a look at better implementation http://www.ourtuts.com/create-a-drop-down-navigation-menu-with-html5-and-css3/

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a duplicate of [How to keep the parent menu hovered while the mouse in child menu in a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103857/how-to-keep-the-parent-menu-hovered-while-the-mouse-in-child-menu-in-a-dropdown?rq=1)

Anyway, put the hover pseudo-class on `li` - change

```
#access ul#menu-top_nav li a:hover {
    background: #336c82;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

to:

```
#access ul#menu-top_nav li:hover a {
    background: #336c82;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```